# Specifying @RequestHeader once for all controllers in Spring Boot app

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot app with multiple controllers serving various REST methods.  Each of the methods require that the same header parameter be defined.  Is there a way to specify something like the following one time for all controller methods?

```
public ResponseEntity get(@RequestHeader(value="NAME", required = true) String name, ...) {
   ...
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can probably achieve this using `@ModelAttribute`, like this:

```
public class Something {
  private name;
  //...
}

@ModelAttribute("something")
public Something addSomething(@RequestHeader(value="NAME", required = true) String name) {
  return new Something(name);
}

@RequestMapping("/something")
public ResponseEntity get(@ModelAttribute Something something) {
  //...
}
```

You can implement the `@ModelAttribute` populating method in a single Controller or in a `@ControllerAdvice` class, in order to assist multiple controllers. [See reference documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-modelattrib-methods).

Comment: This doesn't seem a good idea to tightly couple - use it ONLY AND ONLY if you have multiple endpoints in the controller and all of them require these headers as mandatory;

Comment: This is literally the original requirement from the OP. And this doesn't mean you need to inject that type in all your controllers.