# Add mandatory headers in all spring boot api without swagger

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security, swagger

**Problem statement:**
I am trying to figure out a way on how can I make a header mandatory for all requests in a spring boot application by writing code at 1 place only. It can be achieved via swagger, but as swagger is disabled on production environment it is not helpful.
**Existing Solution:**
Currently I am adding 
`@RequestHeader String authorization`
 in all method signature to make it mandatory.
**Acceptance Criteria for solution:**

1. Write code at only 1 place to make any particular header mandatory for all requests.
2. If swagger configuration is enabled, then swagger should make it mandatory in all requests while showing it on swagger ui
3. Also is there a way where I can disable only the swagger-ui but the rules defined in Docket bean(swagger) are enabled

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31497786/specifying-requestheader-once-for-all-controllers-in-spring-boot-app

Comment: I recommend aspectJ.